# If a hashmap (dictionary) and a key of his is defined, why is the dot access undefined?

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I am iterating through a hashmap, I can see in the console that both the hashmap `r` and one if its keys `k` is defined (as well as the corresponding value `v`):

```
r
Object {sent020: Object, sent005: Object, sent007: Object, sent002: Object, sent006: Object…}
k
"sent020"
v
Object {org: "someorg", uptime: Object, ip: "10.10.01.1", countryCode: "FR", memory: Object…}
```

I cannot however access `r.k`:

```
r.k
undefined
```

**I was expecting to find that `r.k` is `v`. Why isn't it so?**

Sorry if this is obvious, I am new to Javascript and the equivalent code in Python yields the expected result:

```
>>> r = {"sent20": {"org": "someorg", "ip": "10.10.01.1"}}
>>> for k,v in r.items():
...     print(k, v, r[k])
...
sent20 {'org': 'someorg', 'ip': '10.10.01.1'} {'org': 'someorg', 'ip': '10.10.01.1'}
```

Comment: I would think you'd expect `r.sent020` to access the property `sent020` of `r`. Why then do you expect `r.k` to access the property `sent020`, even though there's no discernible difference in syntax?

Comment: @deceze: since the value of `k` is `sent020` then why `r.k` isn't the  same as `r.sent020`? This is why I added a Python code to hopefully have an explanation of the difference.

Comment: r.k is r["k"] and not r[k], same in both languages

Comment: So any time you have a variable in scope that matches a property name, the variable value is used instead of the property name you think you're writing? Doesn't sound very sane.